# Prototype methods not seen in NodeJS session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I'm trying to learn Javascript and NodeJS by building a small game, and I'm running into a problem. When I attach an object to a session, whenever I reaccess that session I no longer have access to any prototype methods I define on it.

In one file called `24.js`, I have

```
function Deck() {
    this.cards = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        this.cards[i] = Math.floor(i / 4) + 1;
    }
    this.done = false;
}

function GameState() {
    // holds game state and game logic
    this.time = 0;
    this.score = 0;
    this.deck = new Deck();
    this.deck.deal();
}
Deck.prototype.deal = function() {
    // not that important
}

var gameMaker = exports = module.exports = function() {
    return new GameState();
}
```

Then in my main file I have

```
var express = require('express');
var gameMaker = require('./24.js');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'supersecret',
    key: 'express.sid'
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.session.game) {
        req.session.game = gameMaker();
    }
    var game = req.session.game;
    // Access data from game to send to client
});

app.post('/verify', function (req, res) {
    // assumes game exists, check for this later
    var game = req.session.game;
    game.score += 1;
    game.deck.deal();
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

I get an error whenever I do the POST, because it says `Object #<Object> has no method 'deal'`. I checked and I can still call the `deal()` method the first time I load the page, and I can access other information as well (like the score of the game, or what cards were last dealt.) The only thing that breaks is method calls on the same session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that generally when sessions are saved between requests, they are serialized with `JSON.stringify(req.session)`. That means that all objects are converted to plain JS objects and the object will no longer have its prototype set to `Deck.prototype` when it is parsed back from JSON.

You should not be storing complex data structures in your session. Instead have your own logic to get/set session values that are needed to properly recreate the deck.

Comment: Is there a standard way to do this? I'm thinking I'll probably just have a server-side store that maps session IDs to game states.